# Filter mutliple tables with one Tile

Tags: reporting-services, filter, tiles, powerpivot, powerview

i am currently trying to Filter all of my Tables in a sheet using one Tile for the Employees.

I have tried selecting everything, but then The Tile Button gets greyed out.

is there anyway of filterin everyithing through 1 ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by tile? I think we would need a little more detail/explanation to be able to help.

Comment: Think i've found the Answer
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/powerview/thread/0edc0217-a285-4fc6-9986-eaf125490bc5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer i got on TechNet Forums

[TechNet - Filter Multiple tables with one Tile](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/powerview/thread/0edc0217-a285-4fc6-9986-eaf125490bc5/)